# c - properly allocate memory for a struct containing an array of another struct

Tags: c, memory

I want to allocate memory for a struct that contains an array of another struct named `table`. I detected that when assigning the pointers to the functions at the end, the variables in the `linkedObjects` array get corrupted so i think my handling of dynamic memory is wrong.

This is how i'm doing it now:

```
typedef struct Object {
    void *key;
    struct Object *top;
    struct Object *next;
} Object;

typedef struct Table{
    Object *linkedObjects;
    size_t size, originalSize;
    HashFcn hfun;
    PrintFcn pfun;
    ComparisonFcn fcomp;
} Table;

TableP CreateTable(size_t tableSize, HashFcn hfun, PrintFcn pfun, ComparisonFcn fcomp)
{
    int i;
    struct Table *table = malloc(sizeof(table));
    if (table==NULL)
    {
        ReportError(MEM_OUT);
        return NULL;
    }
    table->linkedObjects = NULL;
    table->linkedObjects  = malloc(tableSize * sizeof(Object));

    for(i=0;i<tableSize;i++)
    {

        table->linkedObjects[i].next = malloc( MAX_IN_LIST*sizeof(Object) );
        table->linkedObjects[i].top = malloc( MAX_IN_LIST*sizeof(Object) );
        table->linkedObjects[i].key = NULL;
        table->linkedObjects[i].top->key = NULL;
        table->linkedObjects[i].next->key = NULL;

        if (table->linkedObjects[i].next == NULL)
        {
            ReportError(MEM_OUT);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    table->size = tableSize;
    table->originalSize = tableSize;
    table->hfun = hfun;
    table->pfun = pfun;
    table->fcomp = fcomp;
    return table;
}
```

**Edit:** I edited the function code to reflect the answers:

```
TableP CreateTable(size_t tableSize, HashFcn hfun, PrintFcn pfun, ComparisonFcn fcomp)
{
    int i;
    struct Table *table = malloc(sizeof(table));
    if (table==NULL)
    {
        ReportError(MEM_OUT);
        return NULL;
    }
    table->linkedObjects = NULL;
    table->linkedObjects  = malloc(tableSize * sizeof(Object));

    if (table->linkedObjects == NULL)
    {
        ReportError(MEM_OUT);
        return NULL;
    }

    for(i=0;i<tableSize;i++)
    {
        table->linkedObjects[i].next = NULL;
        table->linkedObjects[i].top = NULL;
        table->linkedObjects[i].key = NULL;
    }

    table->size = tableSize;
    table->originalSize = tableSize;
    table->hfun = hfun;
    table->pfun = pfun;
    table->fcomp = fcomp;
    //printf("%p\n", table->hfun);
    return table;
}
```

but still when i get to the point of the assignments at the end, the `table->linkedObjects[0].key` that is null and value is `0x0` get's overrun to a value `0x8048cc0`. This occurs when this line is executed:

```
table->originalSize = tableSize;
```

**Another Edit:** Confirmed that it happens randomly in the last calls (not only in the line above):

```
table->size = tableSize;
table->originalSize = tableSize;
table->hfun = hfun;
table->pfun = pfun;
table->fcomp = fcomp;
```

Comment: are you meaning to give next and top large amount of memory? From my understanding those object should only need to store one struct in them, unless next and top are arrays in themselves.

Comment: no i won't need alot of memory, just as you said - one struct

Comment: at the moment next and top are independent arrays holding their own set of objects, is this on purpose? I'm trying to understand what you're trying to do here. I would guess next and top should be apart of an array `key`

Comment: next and top are pointers to a struct

Comment: `top` and `next` are mysterious. What do they do? Why are you allocating an array for each one, and only initializing one field of the first object? Other than that I don't see anything particularly wrong with this code. The error may well be elsewhere. Well, unless MAX_IN_LIST is 0, in which case that's just wrong.

Comment: +1 for not destroying the original code when you edited the question.

Comment: @n.m. please review my edit. I'm trying to build a linked list using a struct. next and top are pointers to other objects of type object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`struct Table *table = malloc(sizeof(table));`

should be

`struct Table *table = malloc(sizeof(Table));`

I sometimes love C.

`

Comment: CONFIRMED. spent 2 hours on this and would never caught this without help from a different eye, thank you!

Comment: Firstly, either `struct Table *table = malloc(sizeof(struct Table))` or `Table *table = malloc(sizeof(Table))`. Make up your mind and stick to it. Secondly, I'd say it should be `struct Table *table = malloc(sizeof *table)`. Don't use type names when you don't have to.

Comment: There are lots of possibilities, yeah. I would say `typedef struct table_t Table`. I would *not* use `malloc(sizeof *var)` but rather `((T*)malloc(sizeof(T)))`, wrapped in a macro, as in GNU libiberty. Macros are evil but some things are even more evil. But whatever melts your butter.

Comment: Agree with @AndreyT here. Being able to use `struct Table *table = malloc(sizeof(Table))` is bound to cause confusion because of the `typdef` for `Table` in the OP's code.

Second, I think the most correct answer is `Table *table = malloc(sizeof *table);` as stated by @AndreyT in the answer below. If `table` is changed to a new type, the allocation is still the correct size. 

I believe the first assignment, `struct Table *table = malloc(sizeof(table));` is allocating for the size of the pointer-to-Table, but I'm happy for the correct opinion here.

Comment: @KyleWpppd: Yes, it allocates for the pointer size. That's actually the error this answer is addressing.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, get rid of the habit of using type names under `sizeof`. This is how your memory allocations should have looked

```
Table *table = malloc(sizeof *table);
...
table->linkedObjects = malloc(tableSize * sizeof *table->linkedObjects);
```

That would also fix the "typo" error in the first allocation.

Answer (score 0):

```
table->linkedObjects[i].next = malloc( MAX_IN_LIST*sizeof(Object) );
table->linkedObjects[i].top = malloc( MAX_IN_LIST*sizeof(Object) );
```

This doesn't seem to make sense. When I see `next` or `top` with collections, I expect a single pointer to one `Object` (to the next item in the collection or to the first item in the collection).

Did you mean to do the following:

```
for(i=0;i < (tableSize-1);i++)
{
    table->linkedObjects[i].top = table->linkedObjects[0];
    table->linkedObjects[i].next = table->linkedObjects[i+1];
    table->linkedObjects[i].key = NULL;
}
```

This will allocate memory for each `Object`, and sets up the pointers afterwards.

Comment: i'm already doing that allocation but would it allocate memory for each object also?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. You don't need to allocate memory for `top` or `next`, as you already have allocated those in the array itself. You are using the pointers to point back to certain elements in the array. If you were to allocate extra memory and use new `Object`s for each pointer, it won't point where you are expecting it. You want it to point the ones in the array, not to newly allocated ones.

Comment: i want everything to be null but it should have enough memory later on. Please review my edit